# Gson failure to conver symbols

Tags: json, gson

I am using the Gson function `toJson` for the `=`, `>` and `<` operators, and in the final string they are interpreted as `\u003e`.

Is there a special feature I need to add or take care of?

Comment: sure, but i want it to appear as > in the final string, because i want to post it to a service.

Comment: it is as `>` in the final string. All you have to understand is printing unicode strings.

Comment: @brbtsl: The service should handle `\u003e` perfectly fine, unless its JSON parser is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should **disable HTML escaping**, here is a sample that illustrates it:

```
Gson gson1 = new Gson();

String s1 = gson1.toJson("<>");

Gson gson2 = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();

String s2 = gson2.toJson("<>");
```

s1: "\u003c\u003e"

s2: "<>"