# GSON library ignoring + symbol in the value field

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a simple json which I convert to Java using the `GSON` library.

```
{
    "name" : "DOB",
    "operator" : "<",
    "value" : "CURRENTDATE + 3"
}
```

When I do a gson.fromJson, the value part gets returned as "`CURRENTDATE   3`". The `+` symbol gets ignored.

Is there some setting needed in gson call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gson failure to conver symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092044/gson-failure-to-conver-symbols)

Comment: I'm not sure that the symbol is being ignored, or rather converted to something else.  Anyway, the link I gave looks like a good starting point.

Comment: I checked with <, > symbols and they get considered correctly. Strangely, it ignores the + symbol.  I also tried setting disableHtmlEscaping() ... But, it did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven dependency for gson

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Code Snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonString = "{\"name\" : \"DOB\", \"operator\" : \"<\", \"value\" : \"CURRENTDATE + 3\"}";
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
    Test test = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Test.class);
    System.out.println(test);
}

public class Test {
    String name;
    String operator;
    String value;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test [name=" + name + ", operator=" + operator + ", value=" + value + "]";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Test [name=DOB, operator=<, value=CURRENTDATE + 3]
```